# Visual studio mac Scrolling issue

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-macros

With some applications the scroll bar freezes when scrolled, as you can see from the Gif, it will scroll but all the UI will stick, until the cursor is run over the top of it, this only happens in some applications such as Visual Studio, it use to happen in XCode, but has since fixed its self, Any ideas on what is causing this issue, and how to fix it.
[Gif showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsEJH.gif)